# Closest integer value to 20

Tags: java, division

If I have a number greater than 20 but that can be divided evenly by 2 without any remainder, I want to determine what number gets me closest to 20. For example:

For 2048, dividing by 2 enough times would get me to 16 which is the closest I can get to 20. If the number is 800, the closest is 25.

I can write a loop and just keep dividing and comparing the range and pick the value that is closest. Is there maybe a simpler way, possibly through shifting bits?

EDIT: When I say it evenly divides by 2, I mean it divides all the way down to 2 as well. A number of 70 would only divide down to 35 evenly. A number like 2048 or 1024 will divide evenly all the way to 2.

Sample numbers: 2048, 1920, 1600, 1536, 1080..640, 352, 320, 176. These are typical image sizes from cameras.

Comment: You need to check if your value is even on each step, so in any case you need a loop.

Comment: What would you do with those number that cannot be divided by 2 without remainder (e.g. odd numbers, like 35?)

Comment: He wants to do it for even numbers only.

Comment: For no reason other than to satisfy my curiosity... what is the use case for this?

Comment: @Swapnil but 70 is even and will lead to 35

Comment: What's the use for this? Dividing the width of an image by an equal number of grid columns where the width of the column is closest to 20 pixels. All images are divisible by 2.

Comment: OMG The answer is 42!  Divide it by 2 and you get 21 which is the closest integer to 20 without being 20.

Comment: Peter: Is that a joke?? If so, please piss off.

Comment: @AndroidDev Please consider that your question does not seem to be terribly well-worded and thus invites jokes.

Comment: It is very well worded. What part can't you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input number is `x`, I think you want `x/2^[(log x/14)/log 2]`, assuming you want your target number to be in the interval `[14,27]`.

In java code, `Math`'s `log` function will come in handy (although base-2 logarithm would be even better), and you also need an integer cast (or somehow find the largest integer smaller than the expression in `[]`).

What this does: Let `x` be your input and `y` be the number you want to find. Then, `x=y*2^n` for yet unknown `n`, while `y` is around 20 (see above). Obviously, `n` is the base-2 logarithm of `x/y`. Now, if you pick the smallest possible `y`, call it `y'`, the integer part of the base-2 logarithm of `x/y'` is still the `n` we are looking for, unless `x/y'` differs from `x/y` by a factor of more than 2, which by assumption of repeated division by 2 it cannot. Thus, we have `n` and hence `y=x/2^n`.

Comment: explain your formula please

Comment: Yes, please do. I wonder if the up-voters understood the formula, or just thought "Hmmm, that looks clever!".

Comment: *closest to 20* not the same as *around 20*. For example, for input `70` algorithm must produce `35`

Comment: Erm..."that looks clever"?! Maybe rather "that looks like an application of high-school math"? ;-) Anyway, typing the explanation took much longer than the interval between posting the answer and your comments.

Comment: I don't see how that works. I punched in some numbers and didn't get any integer values. Not even close.

Comment: @mishadoff Well, then replace 14 by 20 if you want 20 to be the lower bound. If you want the result for 90 to be 45 and then stop because 45 is odd, this will not work, but I cannot see how this is implied by the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev Which numbers did you punch in? You only gave 2048 and 800 as examples, for which the above produces your stated desired results.

Comment: OK, it does work. I punched in 14 in your equation but should have used 20. Not sure why you wrote [14,27]. I don't need a range. Thanks a million. I always love math gurus. One line of code sure beats 6 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You effectively want to trim all the trailing zero bits until you have a number which is greater than 13.

Another way to do this is to trim all the zeros, and add them back if the result is too small.

```
public static long func(long num) {
    if (num <= 26) return num;
    long trimZeros = num >>> Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(num);
    while(trimZeros <= 13) trimZeros <<= 1;
    return trimZeros;
}
```

26 is closer to 20 than 13, but 14 is closer to 20 than 28.

Comment: func(2048) would return 32 and not 16 as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use shifting you could start with something like this:

```
public static int func2(int val) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int close = 0;
    while (val > 1) {
        val = val >>> 1;
        if (Math.abs(val - 20) < min) {
            min = Math.abs(val - 20);
            close = val;
        }
    }
    return close;
}


public static void main() {
    for ( int i : new int []{2048, 1920, 1600, 1536, 1080, 640, 352, 320, 176}) {
       System.out.println( i + " -> " + func2( i ));
    }
}
```

Prints

```
2048 -> 16
1920 -> 15
1600 -> 25
1536 -> 24
1080 -> 16
640 -> 20
352 -> 22
320 -> 20
176 -> 22
```

Comment: Is there any advantage over dividing by 2? I think, a clever compiler might replace dividings by 2 with a shift anyway.

Comment: @Chris He asked for the posibility to do that with shifting, I don't see an advantage.

Comment: Yes, your answer is ok. I just wondered if it makes any difference.

Comment: Actually I was just trying to avoid loops. arne's solution does this.